# ¿Como guardar cambios?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde necesito que al cerrar la aplicación mantenga el color seleccionado por el usuario, me gustaría[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] que me ayudaran me seria de mucha ayuda de ante mano gracias

Comment: Debes agregar la funcionalidad de guardar el ultimo valor seleccionado, este valor lo puedes guardar en el registro de windows o en un archivo de la aplicacion, incluso en el archivo de configuracion de la aplicacion.

Answer (score 3):

Una opcion podria ser persistir el color en le `Settings` de la aplicacion que se grabarian en el `app.config`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para llegar alli debes ir a las propiedades del proyecto

[How To Use the Settings Class in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C)

[Saving User Settings in Winform Application](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/350010/Saving-User-Settings-in-Winform-Application)

Recuperas el valor usando

```
Textbox1.BackColor = Settings.Default.myColor;
```

y para persistirlo usarias

```
ColorDialog colorDlg = new ColorDialog();

Settings.Default.myColor = colorDlg.Color;
Settings.Default.Save();
```